# Checking Accuracy of GradientBoostingClassifier when predicting class probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, prediction, gbm

While working with GradientBoostingClassifiers, I'm trying to obtain the probability of the classes the model has predicted for which i use the "predict_proba(X)" method. 
But I would like to know how to check the accuracy of this prediction.

```
P = np.array(D1.drop(['Class'], axis = 1))
q = np.array(D1['Class'])
P_train, P_test, q_train, q_test = train_test_split(P, q)

qst = GradientBoostingClassifier(criterion='friedman_mse', init=None,
              learning_rate=0.08, loss='deviance', max_depth=None,
              max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
              min_samples_leaf=1,
              min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
              n_estimators=400, presort='auto', random_state=None,
              subsample=0.8, verbose=0, warm_start=False).fit(P_train, q_train)
```

The total dataset is of (17520x24) - 24 features including the "Class" Feature
The above code has 3 classes

```
pred_prob_P_test = qst.predict_proba(P_test)
```

This gives the percentage probability of the target belonging to each Class

I would like to check the accuracy of this predicted probability.

Comment: Please give us your current code

Comment: @ArtemisFowl, I just edited with code and some comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

pred_prob_P_test = qst.predict(P_test)
accuracy_score(q_test, pred_prob_P_test)
```

Using `accuracy` as a metric is fine if you need it just for reporting something understandable by anyone. However, you should optimize your model using some other metric like multiclass log loss.

EDIT:

```
pred_prob_P_test = qst.predict_proba(P_test)
preds = np.argmax(pred_prob_P_test, axis=1)
accuracy_score(q_test, preds)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I have tried this. This gives me a one set of predicted classes. But my goal is to find the probability of classes occurring for each target value. Which is why I prefered to use: 
    qst.predict_proba(P_test)
I wanted to know if there is a way to check the accuracy for this.

Also, since I'm a beginner, I would like to know how I could optimize using the log loss, I get the log loss value for this current run, and do I have to loop this?

Comment: Edited my answer above. Although you can call `predict` to calculate the accuracy and then `predict_proba` to get the probabilities. To optimize the log loss (or whichever metric), please google 'cross validation'. Scikit has a most - if not all - of the functionality you'll need.